# Encapsulate an Elastic Search cluster in an of the shelf product

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to provide a product which is installed on up to 10-20 servers and encapsulates an Elastic Search cluster internally as part of the product.
The product must be self managed and work 100% of time without any human intervention.
I'm concerned whether such an ES cluster can be maintained only programmatically while recovering events of hardware failure, power outage and other unexpected events
Or such cluster must have a human administrator "keeping it up".
I'll appreciate inputs from people who have done such thing, or maintain a cluster and thinks it isn't possible.

Comment: You can either dockerize your cluster or subscribe to [Elastic Cloud](https://www.elastic.co/cloud) (or [similar alternatives](https://www.slant.co/options/569/alternatives/~elastic-cloud-alternatives))

Answer (score 0):

You basically can automate via [cluster](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster.html) and [cat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat.html) api

The other question is how much you need to do, also what action should be taken if for instance your app is growing and 10 servers in not enough or you are running our of space.

Also what to do with software updates and so on. So basically you can automate a lot but still i think sometimes you need a human..